# Python note book autocomplete not working in VSCode with environment being CVE

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have done some research, but none of the solutions work for me and it seems that my situation is much worse than everybody else. Currently, my VSCode editor is just acting like a plain text editor for any `ipynb` files. For example, this is how my import block looks like:
[image]

Nothing has been highlighted, and I'm working with this for quite a long time and now I can't bear with this anymore. If this is not bad enough, then take a look at the following:
[image]

Literally, nothing happens. I think now the only help I get from VSCode is plain text auto-completion, but that is far from what anyone should have.

The configuration is pretty simple. I have the following kernels I can choose from:
[image]

And I'm mainly using anaconda3 for my kernel. Further, I only have
[image]

in my `setting.json` for `python` configuration.

As for extension, I have the standard [python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension with [python extension pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python-extension-pack) installed, which are the only two extensions I installed for `python`.

I'm really tired of working with plain text `python` code, if any information is needed, I can provide as much as I can.

-- Edit

It seems that the default language is not python, but CVE. Futhermore, I can't find the proper language to choose. All the language options are listed below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happened because of the extension **Dependency Analytics**. Please uninstall it and reload window.

Reference: [jupyter conflict with Dependency Analytics](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7914).

Comment: Removing the extension "Dependency Analytics" fixed the issue. The CVE is gone and Python now selectable for the kernel

Answer (score 1):

Click here and select `Python`.
[image]

CVE seems to be the default language for notebooks for some reason. Please check the settings.

Comment: I have updated my posts, which shows that there is no python available...

Comment: It seems that the implementation for the identifier "python" has been overwritten by [MagicPython](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=magicstack.MagicPython), so uninstall the MagicPython extension. It was last updated in 2018 and does not appear to be maintained.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem. And it seems that CVE environment is pretty rare, at least when I want to search for some info.

Comment: Then try extension bisect. (select `Help: Start Extension Bisect` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette))

Comment: Thanks! I identified the problem successfully.